# Error in remote server: (406) No acceptable

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to send Documents to an API to be stored.

My code is:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://open.domain.com:9090/services/rest/index/my_index/document?login=john&key=bag6swgsalaidhjdh47678sdff");
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Put;
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.Accept = "application/json";
string data = doc.getJSON();
request.ContentLength = data.Length;

StreamWriter postStream = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
postStream.Write(doc.getJSON());
postStream.Close();

try
{
    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
} catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error: "+e.Message);
}
```

It just try to send a Document in JSON format and always return a WebException.

Here you can see the specifications from the documentation as it should be done:

```
curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d '[{"lang": "ENGLISH","fields": [{ "name": "id", "value": 1 }]}]' \
    http://localhost:8080/services/rest/index/my_index/document
```

And here how to authenticate:

```
curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d '[{"lang": "ENGLISH","fields": [{ "name": "id", "value": 1 }]}]' \
    http://localhost:9090/services/rest/index/my_index/document?login=lorem&key=08762e43getye0042f875e86eaiu687f
```

Always received the same exception: Error 406 No acceptable.

So, what's wrong?

**EDIT**:

data in Json format (data):

> {"fields":[{"name":"titulo","value":"el
>   titulo"},{"name":"descripcion","value":"el
>   titulo"},{"name":"free","value":"el
>   titulo"},{"name":"friendly_url","value":"el
>   titulo"},{"name":"ID","value":"el titulo"},{"name":"url","value":"el
>   titulo"},{"name":"url_imagen","value":"el
>   titulo"},{"name":"plataforma","value":"nueva"},{"name":"hide","value":"0"}]

From the documentation

**Inserting documents using JSON**

Use this API to create or update documents in the index.

Requirement: OpenSearchServer v1.5

Call parameters

URL: /services/rest/index/{index_name}/document

Method: PUT

HTTP Header:

Content-Type (required): application/json
Accept (optional returned type): application/json or application/xml

URL parameters:

index_name (required): The name of the index.

Raw data (PUT):
An array of documents.

Comment: Are you sure the API accepts JSON data? 406 seems to imply that it's trying to return a response in a different format, but you specified `Accept: application/json` only.

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan I have posted what indicates the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, there is no requirement to send the `ContentLength` header,

```
request.ContentLength = data.Length;; // <-- remove this line
```

---

Here is a more comprehensive block of code to use:

```
string apiUri = @"http://localhost:8080/services/rest/index/my_index/document";

var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(apiUri);
httpWebRequest.Method = "PUT";  
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
//httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/json";

using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
{
    var data = new List<object>()
    {
        new
        {
            Lang = "ENGLISH",
            Fields = new List<object>()
            {
                new { Name = "id", Value = 1 }
            }
        }
    };
    string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
    streamWriter.Write(json);
}
var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
    var response = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourObjectType>(streamReader.ReadToEnd());
    return response; // do something with the response...
}
```

This will send the equivalent to:

```
curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '[{"lang": "ENGLISH","fields": [{ "name": "id", "value": 1 }]}]' \
http://localhost:8080/services/rest/index/my_index/document
```

Comment: I did exactly the same than you indicate and the same response.

Comment: The error in more detail: Excepción producida: 'System.Net.WebException' en System.dll
Error: NotAcceptable
Error: Connection: close
Content-Length: 176
Content-Type: text/plain
Date: Thu, 22 Jun 2017 17:04:24 GMT
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1

Comment: Are you sure you didn't provide an Accept header?  Status Code `406` usually means that the Accept header is not matching up properly. Unless they are misusing the `406` response.

Comment: @Apalabrados -- take a look at your URI also.

Comment: Take a look at this page: http://www.opensearchserver.com/documentation/api_v2/authentication.md  You can see the update method

Comment: Even without the credentials, the exception is the same. Very strange this situation!

Comment: Hi, I know where's the problem comes from.The problem is when suppling the data serialized in json format. It must be enclosed with []. Thanks for your help. Update your content to validate your answer.